# How to load from browser cache after the resources are cached without reload?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, browser-cache, reload

I am making this webpage:
https://bugs.stringmanolo.ga/

When you visit the page the first time, while you navigate the resources are fetched into browser cache. For example, if you navigate 10 times to updates section of the page, the dev/updates.ff file is requested 10 times to the server.

But the resource should be already cached in the browser. The problem is the resource is requested over and over. Your browser don't start to load from cache until a full reaload is made. If you full reload the webpage you don't request the file to the server anymore.

The solution i think off is to callback a .reload() after all the files are cached in the browser so you don't keep making useless requests to the server and the load times from resources are way faster.

The problem about full reload the webpage is that the user will see a ugly refresh while navigating the web.

Is there any way to load from browser cache in first view without the reload?

Comment: I am not able to see any service worker register on that domain. Please share your service worker code.

Comment: https://github.com/StringManolo/bugWriteups/blob/master/ff.js#L56 This code is being call from the last line of main.js file in the root of same repo. The service worker is the cache.js file. You can go to chrome://serviceworker-internals/ to check service workers. Is not a normal thing that your browser needs reload?

Comment: If  your app is cached in browser and your service worker is in active state then it will load from the cache. No need to reload the app. However if there is an new update on your app and that time you need to reload the browser so that new changes are reflected. In service worker you can do that programmatically also.

Comment: However as I said, when I load this site https://bugs.stringmanolo.ga/ I am not able to see any service worker active at all for this site.

Comment: The problem is i need to reload in the first page view. If i don't, then i will keep requesting files to the server over and over. And that is what i'm triying to avoid. Try to test on another pc/device because i tested on quite a few and the service worker is registered. Try to access offline to the url to check if is actually working but not showing for you. Anyways i think this is not a test things type of question. Do browsers need a reload after cache resources to load them from browser cache? Do I need to do something extra? Is even posible? Is the default behaviour?

Comment: No, as I said, if your app is cached and your service worker is registered then no need to reload the app. Only first time when the app is loaded it does not have anything in brower cached at that time it will load from the server but subsequent request will be served from your cached not server.

Comment: I have navigated to "update" and can see "historylogs.ff" file served from the browser cached not from the server.

Comment: "but subsequent request will be served from your cached not server." This is not happening unless you reload the webpage. You obviously getting files from browser cache now because you reload the page already a bunch of times serching for service workers, etc. But i want this to happens in the first view, without reload the page. It's obviously not working because big images take up to 2 seconds to download but when i reload the image load instanly. I want that once the image is loaded and is in cache, browser load it from cache. But instead, browser is requesting server again to get resource.

Comment: Any particular reason for using ff.js?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but all you have to do is set the response header (from webserver) to **cache resources on browser**.
For example if you set

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=30
```

the browser **will cache** the page for 30 seconds.
So if you open this page (let's say an e-commerce products listing), click a link (let's say a product) and then click the **back button** of the browser, the listing page (first one) will be instantly loaded, because you clicked the back button before 30 seconds (max-age we set).

**Be careful**: if you use "public" instead of "private" your proxy (if you have one, for example CloudFlare) will cache the resource globally. This could be ok for some cases, but not for all. For example if the page contains the name of the customer in the header, caching with "public" will show everyone for 30 seconds the name of the first customer who opened the page.

**Remember**: the browser caches the response of the webserver, so if you change something in the DOM after the page is loaded (let's say you make an ajax call that loads header data on page load) this will not be cached and on back button browser will repeat these operations.